# Simple PowerShell, Variable inside bracket no working

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm missing formatting or something simple having to do with the variable. When I enter the variable data, no output. If I enter the SMTP: address manually script works fine.

```
$EmailAddressAlias=Read-Host "Enter the FULL Email Address to find the associated Mailbox "

Get-Mailbox -Identity * |
Where-Object {$_.EmailAddresses -like 'SMTP:$EmailAddressAlias'} |
Format-List Identity, EmailAddresses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues here, and a suggestion. You've got a variable inside single quotes, and you have no wildcards in your `-like` comparison. In order for the variable to expand into its value you need to use double quotes like this:

```
$_.EmailAddresses -like "SMTP:$EmailAddressAlias"
```

Also, when you use `-like` with no wildcards you may as well be using `-eq`. Lastly, you should really filter at the `Get-Mailbox` level rather than getting all mailboxes, and then filtering for just the one you want. You may want to try this instead:

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter "EmailAddresses -like '*$EmailAddressAlias*'" | Format-List Identity, EmailAddresses
```

Comment: Thanks for the help & for offering a much faster command. Both provided a solution! Went with your suggestion.